# Error when trying to 'Seed' mock db into mock dbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, xunit

I've been searching stack overflow for a solution to this problem but I haven't been able to find that one that fixes my error yet. I'm attempting to write unit test for an API that I developed. I created a mock db and mock context for it but when I try to 'seed' my mock context I'm getting this error.

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AppointmentAPI.UnitTests.DbContextExtensions.Seed(AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models.ApptSystemContext)' and 'AppointmentAPI.UnitTests.DbContextExtensions.Seed(AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models.ApptSystemContext)' [AppointmentAPI.UnitTests, AppointmentAPI.UnitTests]
```

Not really sure what the problem is because it was working fine the other day with no error and then when I started working on it today the error appeared. I'm fairly new to C# and especially writing unit tests for a .net API so any help is greatly appreciated. I'll post my two files below.

DbContextExtensions.cs

```
namespace AppointmentAPI.UnitTests
{
    using System;
    using AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models;

    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static void Seed(this ApptSystemContext dbContext)
        {
            // add entities for dbContext instance
            dbContext.AppointmentSlots.Add(new AppointmentSlots
            {
                SlotId = 1,
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-03-31 00:00:00.000"),
                Time = TimeSpan.Parse("12:00:00.0000000"),
                ApptJson = "{'fname':'Billy','lname':'Joel','age':70,'caseWorker':'Donna', 'appStatus':'finished'}",
                Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-02-24 12:00:00.000")
            });

            dbContext.AppointmentSlots.Add(new AppointmentSlots
            {
                SlotId = 6,
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-07-24 00:00:00.000"),
                Time = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00:00.0000000"),
                ApptJson = "{'fname':'Michael','lname':'Smith','age':52,'caseWorker':'Donna', 'appStatus':'finished'}",
                Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-06-25 09:34:00.000")
            });

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
         }
      }
   }
```

DbContextMocker.cs

```
namespace AppointmentAPI.UnitTests
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models;

    public static class DbContextMocker
    {
        public static ApptSystemContext GetApptSystemContext(string dbName)
        {
            // create option for DbContext instance
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApptSystemContext>()
                                        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: dbName)
                                        .Options;

            // create instance of DbContext
            var dbContext = new ApptSystemContext(options);

            // add entities in memory
            dbContext.Seed(); <-- error happens here

            return dbContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is usually thrown when two or more methods are overloaded with same amount of arguments but in different types

eg:

```cs
static void Seed(this ApplicationDbContext dbContext, string word1, string[] array = null);
static void Seed(this ApplicationDbContext dbContext, string word1, string word2 = null);

dbContext.Seed("test word"); // will throw the exception or will show as an syntax error.
```

With the above two files i dont see any methods as such. A clean and build might work hopefully.